# WPF: ContentControl blocks focusing children elements

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, focus, contentcontrol

I programmatically create the following objects (`MainGrid` is the main grid on the window):

```
        ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
        Grid gr = new Grid();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        MainGrid.Children.Add(cc);
        cc.Content = gr;
        gr.Children.Add(rtb);
```

Then I try to set focus on the `RichTextBox`. I try differenet variants, including `rtb.Focusable = true; rtb.Focus();` and `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(XXX, rtb);` with different elements XXX (cc, gr, MainGrid, this). Nothing helps.

At the same time, if I remove the layer with the `ContentControl` , then it works fine:

```
        Grid gr = new Grid();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        MainGrid.Children.Add(gr);
        cc.Content = gr;
        gr.Children.Add(rtb); rtb.Focus();
```

So it seems that the ContentControl causes the problem that the `RichTextBox` can't be focused.

Unforunately, I receive this ContentControl as an input from another form (so, actually i do not create an instance but I cast the input as `ContentControl`: `cc=(ContentControl)input`). So I can't get rid of this.

Could you please give a suggestion how to set `rtb` focused?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You need to read the [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) pages on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Run it at the window's loaded event.

```
 void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
        Grid gr = new Grid();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        MainGrid.Children.Add(cc);
        cc.Content = gr;
        gr.Children.Add(rtb);
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MainGrid, rtb);
    }
```

Visit this for more info: [FocusManager.SetFocusedElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement(v=vs.110).aspx)